# How to implement a Generic View Model To Display dynamic table in view component

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, .net-6.0, variance

I am trying to define a list of Columns objects That also know what property To get from the object in that row.

```cs
public class Column<T> 
{
   //Column Heading
   public string Name { get; set; }
   //Mapping Expression
   public Expression<Func<T, string>> ValueMapper { get; set; }
}

public class Row<T>
{
   T Data { get; set; }
}

public class Table<T>
{
   IEnumerable<Row<T>> Rows { get; set; }
   IEnumerable<Column<T>> Columns { get; set; }
}
```

Then I plan to have a view that I can pass `Table<T>` to as a view as viewmodel for a view component that can display a table for a list of any type in a dynamic way.. instead of defining all of the tables individually.

My issue is that I cannot specify a generic view model and type constraints don't seem to work.. And the Expression doesn't allow for covariance.

Is this possible?  Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

In the end I want to achieve something like this in a razor view.

(setting type constraint of T in above as `where T : IData`)

```
@model Table<IData>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        @foreach(var col in Model.Columns) 
        {
            <td>@col.Name</td>
        }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach(var row in Model.Rows)
    {
       <tr>
           @foreach(var col in Model.Columns)
           {
                <td>@col.ValueMapper.Compile().Invoke(row.Data)</td>
           }
       </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My problem seems to be that I cannot implicitly cast / pass some concrete `Table<T>` Implementation to the view model. I think Variance is the answer but I'm having trouble gettng it to work since 1) the Data property on `Row<T>` has getter and setter meaning it is invariant right? and 2) The `Expression<Func<T, string>>` property has getter and setter as well and also accepts T as type parameter in Func<in T1, out T2>.. So I think there is a way to achieve this.. I am just stumbling.

**EDIT 2 :**

I was able to achieve what I wanted but had to ditch the lamda expression.. I really wanted to use it but just couldn't get it to work.. Also I removed all generics.  And instead of having a property of "T" (T Data { get; set; }) I instead just typed it to `object`.. and Instead of storing expression on column class instead stored a string property name.  The property name is used by row class to fetch property value using reflection. Sad I had to use reflection but it is working.. I am still looking for a better way.

```cs
public class Table
{
    public IEnumerable<Column> Columns {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Row> Rows {get; set;}
}  

public class Row
{
  public object Data {get; set;}
  public string GetValue(string propertyName) 
  {
    var toReturn = "";
    var pi = Data.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    var value = pi.GetValue(Data);
    if(value == null) 
        return toReturn;

    if(value is DateTime dt)
        toReturn = dt.ToShortDateString();
    else
        toReturn = value.ToString();

     return toReturn;
  }
}

public class Column
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string PropertyName {get; set;}
}
```

In view

```html
@foreach(var row in Model.Rows)
    {
       <tr>
           @foreach(var col in Model.Columns)
           {
                <td>@row.GetValue(col.PropertyName)</td>
           }
       </tr>
    }
```

Comment: @Romka No.. This isn't xaml.  This is an asp.net MVC web app. (.net 6).

Comment: oups... the "ViewModel" keyword has misleaded me. I delet my useless comment, thanks for having pointed it out

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper that accepts a generic table and exposes the column names and values as simple strings:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<string> Columns { get; init; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<IReadOnlyCollection<string>> Rows { get; init; }

    public static ViewModel ForTable<T>(Table<T> table)
    {
        var columns = table.Columns.Select(column => column.Name).ToArray();
        var rows = table.Rows
            .Select(row => table.Columns
                .Select(column => column.ValueMapper(row.Data).ToArray())
            .ToArray();

        return new ViewModel
        {
            Columns = columns,
            Rows = rows
        };
    }
}
```

You wouldn't need to use `Expression` with this approach:

```
public class Column<T> 
{
   //Column Heading
   public string Name { get; set; }
   //Mapping Expression
   public Func<T, string> ValueMapper { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a razor view that can build an html table with ViewModel? Thanks.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `IReadOnlyCollection` .  I'll have to look into that further.